# Android Building ERROR Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string but got: undefined

Tags: android, react-native, built-in, expo-go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjZJJ.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsnrD.png) Here is my written VS code

my error after running
After scanning the QR code to open the app on my phone using Expo Go

tried searching the error on AI
heres what i got But I don't understand
This error message usually occurs when a component is not properly exported from its file. There are a few possible causes for this error, so here are some steps you can take to resolve it:

Check that you have properly exported your component from its file. Make sure that you are using the export keyword before the declaration of your component.

Double-check that you are importing your component correctly in the file where you are using it. If you are using a named export, make sure you are importing it with the correct name. If you are using a default export, make sure you are importing it without braces.

If you are using a third-party library or component, make sure that you are importing it correctly and that it is compatible with your version of React.

If the error still persists, try restarting your development server or clearing your cache.

```
 ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Layout`.

This error is located at:
    in Layout
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in LocationProvider (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by RootRoute)
    in RootRoute (created by ContextNavigator)
    in InitialRootStateProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (created by ContextNavigator)
    in RootRouteNodeProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandler)
    in GestureHandler (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Layout`.

This error is located at:
    in Layout
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in LocationProvider (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by RootRoute)
    in RootRoute (created by ContextNavigator)
    in InitialRootStateProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (created by ContextNavigator)
    in RootRouteNodeProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandler)
    in GestureHandler (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we don't need to import anything from the base `react` library, see how the `<Stack />` component exported from the `_layout.js` is greyed out? this usually means the component is unrecognised by the linter and will cause an error at runtime.

Also, the three grey dots underlining the beginning of the `react` import in your `_layout.js` file will show a message when hovered over with the cursor. I would recommend setting up some linting for your React Native project (`eslint` for example) to make these errors more apparent. Consider doing some research on the component you're trying to render in the `_layout.js` file and make sure you're importing it from the correct package - as far as I know there's no `Stack` component that comes from the standard React library.

Looks like you're using Expo - the [documentation here](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/introduction/) may be of use to get up and running again.

Hope this helps :)